# backbone.js Model Sync and C# .net RESTful web services

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, backbone.js

I'm completely lost and apparently have fall way behind with regards to my web services.  In my current applications I perfer simple ajax calls on .asmx files.  With my latest work I'm trying to implement backbone.js and would like to use the models in conjunction with some RESTful web services.

I know I could override the sync function of backbone but I would really like to utilize it with some .net webservices.

Has anyone done this before and might have an example of how, I can't find an example or tutorial anywhere to even point me in the right direction.  If anyone has any ideas on where I should start.

i can't seem to add a comment but I will be using JSON

Comment: Will you be using XML or JSON?

Comment: Forget about built-in methods and variables, write your own methods instead. After that you can call any web service and save the result in any way as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother with the backbone synch, don't go overriding it,
it will be to tricky to hack in whatever you need.

build  your own ajax calls to the webservice
with callback functions, that put the returnvalues in models or collections 
via the [`model.set(attributes, [options])`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) && [`collection.reset(models, [options])`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset)

Comment: Right, I know this is an option I am just trying to see if I can get it functioning within the already built backbone architecture.

Comment: while i understand your point of view if you say you are trying to test the limits of backbone, or want to learn something on customizing the synch, i doubt using the built in functionality will get you where you want to without risk and in due time. so if it were a project for a client i suggest to do it yourself, if it's a hobby project of which you want to learn as mutch as you can on backbone, by all means try the built in functionality first :), i just gave you a way out for when you really need it :)

Comment: @Sander I think he wants to use the built in functionality just doesnt understand how it works. Maybe? Am I right?

Comment: @MikeFielden Correct I DO want to use the built in functionality if possible

Comment: @colin, i said before it was possible but the huge changes required to make it work are in my opinion not worth it. I am in no way stating it is impossible or anything